# IIS 6 Manager instead of IIS 7 Manager on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I did have IIS 7 manager console originally. I did forget Administrator account password but I had another admin account.

Unfortunately with this account I have only IIS 6 console why and how to fix this ?

Note: this server is a domain controller if ever it matters

Comment: Why are you running IIS Management Console from a Domain Controller?

Answer (score 0):

Using server manager, navigate to features and verify that the IIS Manager is installed (it'll be under the remote server administration tooling).

If it is not installed, add the feature.  If it is, you should be able to find the console in the file system at %windir%\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe